# i want to connect my spring app to atlas but by default it connects to local host

Tags: spring, database, mongodb, spring-boot, atlas

I want to connect to mongo atlas in my application properties i have this

```
spring.data.mongo.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@employeemanager.4vksdbvtj.mongodb.net/EmployeesManager?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=EmployeesManager
```

but this didn't worked. When i post some data it created a test db in local host and stores the data there.

i have also tried  these solutions

```
#spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://test:test@EmployeesManager.mogodb.net/employeesEntity
#spring.data.mongodb.uri =mongodb+srv://test:test@employeemanager.4vkdsbvtj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=EmployeesManager
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://test:test@employeemanager.4vkbvtj.mongodb.net/
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/EmployeeManager
#spring.data.mongo.uri = mongodb+srv://nithish:nithish@Nithish.4vkdsbvtj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=emp
#spring.data.mongo.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@employeemanager.4vkbvtj.mongodb.net/
spring.data.mongo.uri =mongodb+srv://admin:admin@employeemanager.4vkbdsvtj.mongodb.net/
```

I want to connect to mongo atlas in my application properties i have this

```
spring.data.mongo.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@employeesmanager.4vkbdsvtj.mongodb.net/EmployeesManager?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=EmployeeManager
```

but this didn't worked. When i post some data it created a test db in local host and stores the data there.

i have also tried  these solutions

```
#spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb+srv://test:test@EmployeesManager.mogodb.net/employeesEntity
#spring.data.mongodb.uri =mongodb+srv://test:test@employeemanager.4vksdbvtj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=EmployeeManager
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://test:test@employeemanager.4vkbsadvtj.mongodb.net/
#spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/EmployeesManager
#spring.data.mongo.uri = mongodb+srv://nithish:nithish@Nithish.4vkasdbvtj.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=emp
#spring.data.mongo.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@employeemanager.4vdakbvtj.mongodb.net/
```

Comment: did you just post your database server url and credentials on the internet? lolz

Comment: Any way i am just using for learning purposes

Comment: The database `employeemanager` must come after the hostname, not before.

Comment: Can u provide the correct uri